How to use .sty file with Quarto Book
I have to write a thesis that also contains code written in R and the related plots, so structuring the thesis like a book in Quarto is much more convenient for me than writing it directly in Latex.
However, I would like to use the Cleanthesis Style to add some embellishment effect. However, this style comes with the cleanthesis.sty file, but i don't know how to tell Quarto to use it as a template.
Is there a way to use a .sty file as a template for Quarto? And if so, would there be someone who can explain to me step by step how to setup it from a basic Quarto new document>book?
Thanks in advance

Welcome. // What you can always do is saving the .sty file in your documents main directory. Next put \usepackage{… .sty} in your preamble as usual. This works locally, for this document.

This is not a template, it is a just latex package. The difference matter. There are at least two  ways to include a  package In Quarto documents:  One is use in a custom pandoc template including this package, another is  set custom templates  but use  include-in-header:  YAML option to add it to the default latex preamble. Of course, the package should be in the current directory or a searchable path.
